# C - Buffer size reduced after being passed to another function

Tags: c

I'm working on an assignment in C and while tracing an error, I've encountered something I, as a beginner, do not understand.

What I'm doing is memcpying some variables to a buffer in a function `l1_connect()`:

```
int l1_connect(const char* hostname, int port) {
    // Variables to be stored in the buffer
    char *msg = "Hi, I'm a message"; // strlen(msg) == 17
    uint16_t sender_id = htons(1); // sizeof(sender_id) == 2
    uint16_t packet_size = htons(sizeof(packet_size)+sizeof(sender_id)+strlen(msg)); // sizeof(packet_size) == 2

    // The buffer
    char buf[100];

    // Copying everything
    memcpy(&buf, &sender_id, sizeof(sender_id));
    memcpy(&buf+sizeof(sender_id), &packet_size, sizeof(packet_size));
    memcpy(&buf+sizeof(sender_id)+sizeof(packet_size), &msg, strlen(msg));

    printf("l1_connect - sizeof(buf): %d\n", (int)sizeof(buf)); // == 21

    // Passing buf to another function
    int bytes_sent = l1_send(1, buf, sizeof(buf));

    return bytes_sent;
}
```

In the end of this function, the size of the buffer is 21. After passing it to another function, however, it's apparently 8.

```
int l1_send( int device, const char* buf, int length ) {
    printf("l1_send - Sizeof buf: %d\n", (int)sizeof(buf)); // == 8
    printf("l1_send - Sizeof &buf: %d\n", (int)sizeof(&buf)); // == 8
    printf("l1_send - Sizeof *buf: %d\n", (int)sizeof(*buf)); // == 1
    printf("l1_send - Sizeof &buf[0]: %d\n", (int)sizeof(&buf[0])); // == 8

    return 1; // For now
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what I am missing?

I'm trying to send the buffer over a UDP socket and then extract those three variables again. Extracting `sender_id` and `packet_size` works fine, but the message keeps giving errors or null-values, and I'm assuming it's because of the buffer size issue.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Much appreciated, guys! I've come to realize why we're passing `length` to `l1_send()`

Comment: sizeof(const char *) gives you the size of the pointer, not the thing being pointed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` is an operator that return the size of the variable type, not the size of the allocated buffer.

so, on what seems to b 64 bit machine:

```
// l1_send

sizeof(buf) --> size of char * --> 8 bytes
sizeof(&buf) --> size of char ** --> 8 bytes
sizeof(*buf) --> size of char --> 1 byte
sizeof(&buf[0]) --> size of char * --> 8 bytes

// l1_connect
sizeof(buf) --> size of char[100] --> 100 bytes (that's what it should be)
```

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the first related question also addresses this. I'm guess I'm not that great at searching

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of an array, you should use this snippet:

```
int buff[100];
int buff_size = sizeof(buff) / sizeof(buff[0]);
```

Beyond that, doing a `sizeof` a pointer, you'll most certainly get `4` or `8` byte, depending on the architecture.
Thus, there is some kind of *information loss* when you convert from an array to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// The buffer
char buf[100];
const char * buff_size = buf; 

sizeof(buf);  // This is valid
sizeof(buff_size);
```

Later one the compiler doesn't know where it is pointing too. As `sizeof()` works at compile time, `sizeof(buff_size)` will return 8 bytes